# Returning an object from coffeescript in backbone

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, coffeescript

I guess I am missing something very basic here. I just want to get the value from the function in coffeescript. I am doing console.log for that value..

```
class App.Views.PlotModal extends Backbone.ModalView
  template: JST['plots/plot_modal'],

  render: ->
    console.log(@getSize.w);
    $(@el).html(@template(plot: @model));
    this.showModal();

  getSize: ->
    cell_div = document.getElementById("bgr");
    w : cell_div.offsetWidth * 3;
    h : cell_div.offsetHeight * 2;
```

When I go to console in firebug I keep getting undefined. If I log just @getSize, I get the function back. How do I return the variables w and h here?

Also  is it a good idea to do this kind of operation (I want to dynamically resize iframe) in backbone view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CoffeeScript, this leaves the method `f` in the variable `x` as a simple function:

```
x = @f
```

If you want to call the function then you have to supply arguments:

```
x = @f 'pancakes'
```

or add parentheses:

```
x = @f()
```

So you want this:

```
console.log(@getSize().w)
```

As far as doing this sort of thing in Backbone goes, sure, why not? Backbone tends to leave policy up to you.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot! can you comment on the second part - does this kind of functionality belong in backbone view?

Comment: @Stpn: I think I added the "sure, why not?" bit after your first reading. I don't see any reason why you wouldn't, a dialogish `<iframe>` is as much a view as anything else and the view should take care of itself as much as possible.